# How to set locale in Debian 6.0.3?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, localization

How to set locale in Debian 6.0.3?

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
[sudo] password for foobar: 
locales-all installed, skipping locales generation
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running `locale-gen` - this will re-compile a list of all available locales.

Comment: It worked. Any idea how it got messed up at the first place? How did you know it was broken locale file? Or was it?

Comment: I've come across that once before on my own Debian installs; For some reason or another there's a list of 'available locales' that never got generated; as to why is beyond me.